# Var with number of files gulp-count

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have a Gulp task, where it return me the number of files inside a folder.
The task works correctly, but I need get this value to make an "If" to order it.

My task:

```
gulp.task('numberFiles', function() {
    nmFiles += gulp.src('finals/**.*')
        .pipe(count('<%= counter %>'));
        return true;
});
```

With this value I would like to make my custom task like it:

```
gulp.task('ordermyfiles',['copying'], function() {
    return gulp.src('finals/_*.js') 
        .pipe(order([

            //loop to order my files 
            //I need the value of  count('<%= counter %>');
            //With count('<%= counter %>') just recive and object
            "finals/_file1.js",
            "finals/_file2.js",
            "finals/_file3.js",
            "finals/_file4.js",
        ]))
        .pipe(concat("FinalFile.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/"));
});
```

Somebody knows, how Can I implement it?

BR,
Christian

Comment: Have you tried just using `gulp-sort` for sorting the files automatically? https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sort

Comment: Yes I have it, but I need a specific order of my js files. I would like to order with the nambe of my files... like 1_file.js, 2_file.js ....

Comment: Sorry @DanielDiekmeier, I understand gulp-sort, hahah I'll go to try it. Thanks Bro.